# Useful Mercurial Hooks

Tags: mercurial, hook, mercurial-hook

What are some useful Mercurial hooks that you have come across?

A few example hooks are located in the [Mercurial book](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html):

- [acl](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html#id404286)
- [bugzilla](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html#id404689)
- [notify](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html#id405642)
- [check for whitespace](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html#id403945)

I personally don't find these very useful. I would like to see:

- Reject Multiple Heads
- Reject Changegroups with merges (useful if you want users to always rebase)

  - Reject Changegroups with merges, unless commit message has special string
- Automatic links to Fogbugz or TFS (similar to bugzilla hook)
- Blacklist, would deny pushes that had certain changeset ids. (Useful if you use MQ to pull changes in from other clones)

Please stick to hooks that have either bat and bash, or Python. That way they can be used by both *nix and Windows users.

Comment: Perhaps more ideas can be gleaned from these Subversion questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155/common-types-of-subversion-hooks and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884608/share-common-useful-svn-pre-commit-hooks ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My favorite hook for formal repositories is the one that refuses multiple heads.  It's great when you've got a continuous integration system that needs a post-merge tip to build automatically.

A few examples are here: [MercurialWiki: TipsAndTricks - prevent a push that would create multiple heads](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Prevent_a_push_that_would_create_multiple_heads)

I use this version from Netbeans:

```
# This software may be used and distributed according to the terms
# of the GNU General Public License, incorporated herein by reference.
#
# To forbid pushes which creates two or more headss
#
# [hooks]
# pretxnchangegroup.forbid_2heads = python:forbid2_head.forbid_2heads

from mercurial import ui
from mercurial.i18n import gettext as _

def forbid_2heads(ui, repo, hooktype, node, **kwargs):
    if len(repo.heads()) > 1:
        ui.warn(_('Trying to push more than one head, try run "hg merge" before it.\n'))
        return True
```

Comment: http://hg.python.org/hooks/file/tips/checkheads.py - this more good as allow branching....

Comment: Indeed, there are some nice variants that allow only one head per named branch (anonymous branching is branching too).

Comment: @gavenkoa: The link should be http://hg.python.org/hooks/file/tip/checkheads.py (not /tips/)

Comment: @gavenkoa: You can only do that up to 5 or 15 minutes after creation, to avoid disruptive changes in discussions. You should maybe post your comment as an answer, since it is much better than the accepted one.

Answer (score 9):

I've just created a small pretxncommit hook that checks for tabs and trailing whitespace and reports it rather nicely to the user. It also provides a command for cleaning up those files (or all files).

See the [CheckFiles](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CheckFilesExtension) extension.

Answer (score 5):

Another good hook is this one. It allows multiple heads, but only if they are in different branches.

[Single head per branch](http://hg.mozilla.org/users/bsmedberg_mozilla.com/hghooks/file/5410ccbb1e43/mozhghooks/single_head_per_branch.py)

```
def hook(ui, repo, **kwargs):
    for b in repo.branchtags():
        if len(repo.branchheads(b)) > 1:
            print "Two heads detected on branch '%s'" % b
            print "Only one head per branch is allowed!"
            return 1
    return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the Single Head Per Branch hook mentioned above; however, `branchtags()` should be replaced with `branchmap()` since branchtags() is no longer available.  (I couldn't comment on that one so I stuck it down here).

I also like the hook from https://bobhood.wordpress.com/2012/12/14/branch-freezing-with-mercurial/ for Frozen Branches.  You add a section in your hgrc like this:

```
[frozen_branches]
freeze_list = BranchFoo, BranchBar
```

and add the hook:

```
def frozenbranches(ui, repo, **kwargs):
    hooktype = kwargs['hooktype']
    if hooktype != 'pretxnchangegroup':
        ui.warn('frozenbranches: Only "pretxnchangegroup" hooks are supported by this hook\n')
        return True
    frozen_list = ui.configlist('frozen_branches', 'freeze_list')
    if frozen_list is None:
        # no frozen branches listed; allow all changes
        return False
    try:
        ctx = repo[kwargs['node']]
        start = ctx.rev()
        end = len(repo)

        for rev in xrange(start, end):
            node = repo[rev]
            branch = node.branch()
            if branch in frozen_list:
                ui.warn("abort: %d:%s includes modifications to frozen branch: '%s'!\n" % (rev, node.hex()[:12], branch))
                # reject the entire changegroup
                return True
    except:
        e = sys.exc_info()[0]
        ui.warn("\nERROR !!!\n%s" % e)
        return True

    # allow the changegroup
    return False
```

If anyone attempts to update the frozen branches (e.g., BranchFoo, BranchBar) the transaction will be aborted.