# Automatically Tag changesets when commit or pushed to kiln

Tags: mercurial, tags, fogbugz, kiln

I would like to know if there is a way to automatically tag a changeset as it is committed locally or when pushed to the kiln repository.

I would like every changeset to have a tag with version/build number. I am planning to store my version/build numbers in a database and would like to have a script retrieve this value from the database and add a tag to the changeset. Is it possible to invoke a script automatically to do this as a post-commit event or as a post-push event when pushed to the kiln repository?

I am also open to any other approaches to achieve automatic tagging on every commit/push.

Comment: Also on the Kiln StackExchange: http://kiln.stackexchange.com/questions/2602/automatically-tag-changesets-when-commit-or-pushed-to-kiln

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than creating a tag for each changeset, why not try one of the following:

- Use the changeset hash as your identifier?
- Use a string generated from the log as your identifier (see below)?

A descriptive string can be generated from the log using this command:

```
hg log -r 1.7.2 --template '{latesttag}-{latesttagdistance}-{node}\n'
```

The result takes the form:

```
<latest tag>-<# changesets since latest tag>-<changeset hash>
```

For example, on my local clone of the Mercurial repo, this generates:

```
1.7.2-2-5e51254ad4d4c80669f462e310b2677f2b3c54a7
```

Which tells me that there have been two commits since tag 1.7.2 and the current changeset hash is 5e51254a.

In Mercurial, each tag creates a new changeset.  So if you tag every commit, you double the number of changesets in the repo.  You should use the built-in tools (as described above) rather than try to recreate the wheel.

Comment: +1 interesting approach! I would use `{short}` instead of `{node}` though, to keep the length of the version descriptor manageable.

Comment: hg log -r tip ... is probably better. {short} doesn't seem to work in 1.4.3 unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know if there is a way to automatically tag a changeset as it is committed locally or when pushed to the kiln repository.

You could always write a post commit hook to do that.

> I would like every changeset to have a tag with version/build number.

Tags are useful to identify important moments in your commit history. Providing those moments a meaningful name that relates to the product development like release 1.0,  release 1.3 etc .

If you were to make a tag every change set then you would just increase noise level. You will still need to keep information about important tags some where.

Consider tag as meta information about change-sets. Not all of them deserve the same importance. Not all of them require that meta information.

Looking at tags can give you meaningful history only when you use them sparingly.

> On hooks

See:

- http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#hooks
- [Useful Mercurial Hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705921/useful-mercurial-hooks)
- https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Hook

Example: Run after a changegroup has been added via push, pull or unbundle. I have used it to trigger automatic builds.

```
[hooks]
changegroup.yyyy = command
```

Similarly, there is post-commit , post-push hooks

```
[hooks]
post-<command> =  command
```