# Mercurial hooks: How can I detect second head in a particular push?

Tags: mercurial, hook, mercurial-hook, mercurial-api

I'm using server-side (remote) hooks to prevent specific kind of pushes.
Among other thing, I want to ban pushes that are creating new heads in mercurial repository even if they were pushed with `--force`.

I can think only of one way to achieve this: just iterate through ancestors and fail on first ancestor that has two children.

This approach actually works, but I'll be very glad if someone can show me a more elegant way of achieving the same.

Comment: Have a look at the existing question and in particular the accepted answer along with its comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705921/useful-mercurial-hooks
Also see https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Prevent_a_push_that_would_create_multiple_heads

Answer (score 1):

OK, so it turns out it's done much easier than I've anticipated. Basically all you need is to check for the number of head in the repo repo object, so:

```
if repo.heads() > 1:
     return True
```

Comment: in addition, your first proposal would not allow branches that split even if they merge and end up with a single head, because there would be a point of bifurcation with two children, therefore rejected

Comment: @arhak good point! In our case though merges are not allowed, so there's no such thing like bifurcation.