# Jalopy to format return/throw statements

Tags: maven-2, formatting, maven-plugin, maven-scm, jalopy

I would like Jalopy to format my return and throw statements such that they look like a method call since they are:

```
return(true);

throw(new IllegalArgumentException("You can't do that, what we you thinking?"));
```

I have the rest of the code formatted exactly the way I want so this is the icing on the cake.

Also as an aside, I work on a project with a few team members and each have our own preference for looking at code, has anyone setup Jalopy in conjuction with a successful build as well as checkout?

So, when I checkout code, it gets formatted to my liking, and then each time I get a successful build, it gets formatted according to the Java/Sun Standard and then checked in?

Walter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like Jalopy to format my return and throw statements such that they look like a method call

I didn't find anything about this in Jalopy's [Manual](http://jalopy.sourceforge.net/jalopy/manual.html) and think this would require extending Jalopy.

> (...) when I checkout code, it gets formatted to my liking, and then each time I get a successful build, it gets formatted according to the Java/Sun Standard and then checked in?

If you are using subversion, maybe you could use a [client-side hook](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/tsvn_1.5_releasenotes.html#client-side-hooks) on checkout and a [pre-commit hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884608/share-common-useful-svn-pre-commit-hooks/1778131#1778131) on commit.

Comment: Thanks Pascal, I double-checked the manual as well and didn't see any options there for that.  I figured I would ask out here as someone is bound to know.

The hooks sound good, but I will have to see what other issues that may bring up.

Answer (score 0):

The commercial Jalopy supports this.

Here are the links for the corresponding user's guide sections:

[Insert throws parentheses](http://www.triemax.com/products/jalopy/manual/java.html#INSERT_PAREN_THROW)